# What is the correct way to derive a classmethod in python?

Tags: python, superclass, metaclass, class-method

Recently, I encountered a problem with metaclass calling a derived classmethod.
For example, I get a simple baseclass `testA`, which has an classmethod `do1(a)`

```
class testA(object):

    @classmethod
    def do1(cls, a):
        print "in testA:",cls, a
```

Then I build a metaclass which actually do nothing but print the cls:

```
class testMetaA(type):
    def __init__(cls,cname,bases,cdict):
        print "in testMetaA: %s"%cls
```

Then I could use the metaclass to build a subclass `testB`, which works as expected:

```
class testB(testA):

    @classmethod
    def do1(cls, a):
        print "in testB: %s"%cls
        super(testB, cls).do1(a)
    __metaclass__=testMetaA
```

It will print: `in testMetaA: <class '__main__.testB'>`; and the `testB.do1(a)` works as expected:

```
>>> testB.do1('hello')
in testB: <class '__main__.testB'>
in testA: <class '__main__.testB'> hello
```

However, if I try to call the classmethod inside the metaclass which contains a "`super`" as following `testMetaB`, it will raise an error: `NameError: global name 'testC' is not defined`.

```
class testMetaB(type):
    def __init__(cls,cname,bases,cdict):
        print "in testMetaB: %s"%cls
        cls.do1("hello")

class testC(testA):

    @classmethod
    def do1(cls, a):
        print "in testC: %s"%cls
        super(testC, cls).do1(a)
    __metaclass__=testMetaB
```

I finally find a way to solve it by use `super(cls, cls)` instead of `super(testC, cls)`:

```
class testD(testA):

    @classmethod
    def do1(cls, a):
        print "in testD: %s"%cls
        super(cls, cls).do1(a)
    __metaclass__=testMetaB
```

It will print as:

```
in testMetaB: <class '__main__.testD'>
in testD: <class '__main__.testD'>
in testA: <class '__main__.testD'> hello
```

The `testD.do1(a)` also works as expected:

```
>>> testD.do1('Well done')
in testD: <class '__main__.testD'>
in testA: <class '__main__.testD'> Well done
```

Now I am wondering which is the most correct way to use super in a classmethod? Should one always use `super(cls,cls)` instead of explicitly writing a current class name?

Thanks!

@jsbueno

> If some piece of code resorts to tricks like dynamically creating derived classes, that is important - one should not use the class name as first parametere to Super if that name is assigned to another object than the class itself. Instead, cls for class methods, or `self.__class__` for instance methods can be passed to Super.

**Does this means it is a bad idea to use class name to super in general?**

To myself, I usually use `super(type(self),self)` instead of `super(type(self.__class__),self)` for normal method. I do not know if there is any major advantage to use `self.__class__`.
I repeat @jsbueno example like this, here the C use `super(type(self),self)`. So `D2()` will not change the behavior while the class `C` gets changed.

```
>>> class A(object):
    def do(self):
        print "in class A"


>>> class B(A):
    def do(self):
        super(B, self).do()


>>> class C(A):
    def do(self):
        super(type(self),self).do()

>>> D1=B
>>> D2=C
>>> D1().do()
in class A
>>> D2().do()
in class A
>>> class B(A):
    def do(self):
        print "in new class B"


>>> D1().do()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#52>", line 1, in <module>
    D1().do()
  File "<pyshell#37>", line 3, in do
    super(B, self).do()
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
>>> class C(A):
    def do(self):
        print "in new class C"
>>> D2().do()
in class A
```

according to @Don Question's suggestion, I put the python version here: sys.version= 2.7.2+ (default, Oct 4 2011, 20:06:09) [GCC 4.6.1]

Comment: @Don Question: "Your Metaclass testMetaA actually does NOT build a class." It will, you can actually try to wrap the function in `__init__`. Without override the metaclass `__new__` does not mean it will not use super-metaclass's `__new__`. You can find a lot of example online. And you should notice that, as in normal class, the `__new__`'s first arg of a metaclass is completely different from the `__init__`'s first arg of the metaclass.

Comment: Except that you want to modify the classname or the base tuple, you can always stick to `__init__`. I think it is more convenient than `__new__`, because within `__init__` after `__new__`, the metaclass's instance cls actually exists. Of cause, within `__new__`, one can also use `cls=super(testMetaB,meta).__new__(meta,cname,bases,cdict)` to build the cls first. Then modify it inside `__new__`.

Comment: To me the `self` is actually refer to an instance of a normal class. I usually use `meta` as first arg of metaclass's `__new__` and `cls` refers to the metaclass's instance (which is a normal class). You can use any word you want, it does not matter. Anyway, it is completely irrelevant to my question.

Comment: @Don Question:"Ahh, you put your metaclass under the method-definitions"; this actually does NOT matter, you can change the position to the first line of class def. It will not affect any thing.

Comment: It may seem to be irrelevant, because you know EXACTLY what you want, but we others don't so we need to understand you unambigously, which makes wording really important and in such complex matters a pain in the ass for the OP. I'm not trying to go on your nerves, but just trying to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Don Question: Sorry, it happens that your comments regarding how metaclass works are wrong. I thing they add confusion to the context here. To make it very clear: (1) The metaclass does not need to specify a `__new__` method. If it isnot there, the default `type`'s `__new__` is used. (2) It is meaningless where on the class body the `__metaclass__` is assigned - it is only taken into account once the class body is parsed and all names assigned in its context are inside a plain dictionary. (Python 3 behaves differently)

Comment: @jsbueno: Where was a comment wrong? I clearly stated i was not sure about the matter if the `__metaclass__` has to stand at the beginning. But thanks that you explained that matter clearly. The wording of the OP suggested he meant to "build" with his following method, which was a `__init__` after he clarified it in his later comment i didn't persue that matter further, because it was evident that he knew what he talked about. If i sound clueless in some regards it's only because i'm still learning and if i find a interesting question i try to understand if i can take something "home" myself.

Comment: So it'S no disrespect or trolling, but quite to the contrary a form of appreciation if i ask annoying questions or state the obvious! ;-)

Comment: DOn Question: the same for me - no harm intended. I just put the correction for your comments in the most direct and plain language I could

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, if I try to call the classmethod inside the metaclass which
>   contains a "super" as following testMetaB, it will raise an error:
>   NameError: global name 'testC' is not defined.

The name `TestC` will only be bound to the new class after the MetaClass finished it's work - and that is after returning from it's `__init__` (and before `__init__`, the  `__new__`) method.

When we use the "super" call usign the class name as the first parameter, the class name does not appear there magically: it is a (module) global variable, to which the class itself is assigned - in normal circunstances.

In this case, the name has not been assigned yet - however, as it is a classmethod, yuu have a reference to the class in the `cls` variable- that is why it works.

If some piece of code resorts to tricks like dynamically creating derived classes, that is important - one should not use the class name as first parametere to Super if that name is assigned to another object than the class itself. Instead, `cls` for class methods, or `self.__class__` for instance methods can be passed to Super.

Here is a snippet showing the global name binding for the class name is what super takes:

```
>>> class A(object):
...   def do(self):
...      print "In class A"
... 
>>> class B(A):
...   def do(self):
...     super(B, self).do()
... 
>>> C = B
>>> C().do()
In class A
>>> class B(object):
...   def do(self):
...      print "in new class B"
... 
>>> C().do()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in do
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
>>>
```

Comment: Would be nice if you could point a little bit more out, whats happening in the crucial parts. If i understand correctly you tried to demonstrate how the second class B is not called through C().do?

Comment: Thanks! For the normal method, I usually do it like this `super(type(self),self).do()`, I think this maybe better than `self.__class__`?

Comment: Wang: indeed - type(self) would be better than `self.__class__` - but both are equivalent.

Comment: jsebueno: If I understood you correctly, you suggest that one should never use a class name in super in general. I agree with this. And for super the `__new__` in any condition, one can actually use `super(meta,meta).__new__(meta, cname, bases, cdict)`. Is this correct?

Comment: Never, ever, ever, use `super(type(self),self).do()`. The first parameter passed to super must be the class containing the current method definition which as soon as you have inheritance is usually *not* the same as the type of the object. You must use the class itself (typically the class name), otherwise as soon as you have multiple levels of subclasses your code will recurse infinitely.

Comment: @Duncan:"Never, ever, ever, use super(type(self),self).do()", then how you plan to solve the problem mentioned by jsebueno?

Comment: By not overwriting the class name when you still need it.

Comment: @Duncan: indeed, if ther eis further subclassing. Although, it is not as bad as "never ever ever", as it will  crash early and repeatbly in the infinite recursion case. Int he example I mentioned, of dynamicly creating subclasses for certaing iven types, for example, I didn't had a variable refencing the class itself (I could have it with an extra closure level), but none of those dynamic class will be subclassed again, so it is not a case of "Never ever ..."